# How to make sphinx behave like postgres similarity?

Tags: postgresql, sphinx

for performance reasons I recently opted for sphinx instead of the similarity function in postgres http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/pgtrgm.html.

However, out-of-the-box sphinx does not behave like the similarity function.

and seems to only match complete words( in my case addresses),

keywords like:
"Main South Rd",
"Field St",
"Olive Av", give no result

I have tried to enable SPH_MATCH_ANY, but with postgres similarity I get much better results.

Comment: min_infix_len = 1 improved the result, but the result is not as good as similarity

Answer (score 1):

To deal with the abbrivations, you could perhaps use wordforms. So that short matches long form.

There is also
http://sphinxsearch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/misc/suggest/
which is an example using trigrams to get fuzzy matches.

If you want more help suggest giving a fuller example, Of the queries that dont work well, and what you matching against.

(I'm guessing you just use similarity() function, by looping over all documents, and take the best matches. Its brute force, checking every document. Sphinx is using an index (which is why it fast) but not all queries are suitable for this type of setup)